# Prime NG : tree propagateSelectionUp in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, tree, primeng

I'm a beginner working on an app built with JHipster and using Angular 4.3 and PrimeNG.
I've a tree and a search bar.

When I open my tree with clicks, the checkboxes are good, like this : 
[image: Tree opened with clicks]

But I've a problem, when I do a research in the search bar, I manually open the tree with typescript code and when I put the right leaf in the selected nodes, it does not check the country and the continent (parent's node) :

[image: Tree opened in typescript]

**Here is my HTML code :**

```
    <jhi-search-bar [data]="items" (onItemSelected)="openNodeAfterSearch($event)"></jhi-search-bar>
    <p-tree class="arbre"
                        [loading]="loading"
                        [value]="nodes"
                        selectionMode="checkbox"
                        (onNodeSelect)="onChange()"
                        (onNodeUnselect)="onChange()"
                        [(selection)]="selectedNodes"></p-tree>
```

**Here is my TS code :**

```
openNodeAfterSearch(item: any) {
    const racine = this.nodes[0];
    // I close all unecessary opened nodes
    for (const continent of racine.children) {
        continent.expanded = false;
        for (const country of continent.children) {
            country.expanded = false;
            for (const item of country.children) {
                if (item.data.id === item.item.id) { // right node to open

                    this.selectedNodes = [];
                    this.selectedNodes.push(item);

                    country.expanded = true; // open parent's node
                    continent.expanded = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried this HTML property but it failed :

```
[propagateSelectionUp]="true"
```

I don't want to proceed like this neither :

```
this.selectedNodes.push(country);
this.selectedNodes.push(continent);
```

Because I obtain this :

[image: All in selectedNodes]

Does anyone has an idea ?

Julie.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution :

```
country.partialSelected = true;
continent.partialSelected = true;
```

Just need to add some conditions to check if all the children are selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** **:)**      !!!!!!!!!

you should use ***bracket*** in this property

[propagateSelectionUp]="false"
[propagateSelectionDown]="false"